# Why does overload resolution pick the wrong overload when providing a template argument explicitly?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, std, shared-ptr

My code is here:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <queue>

template<typename TValue>
[[maybe_unused]]
constexpr auto t1(const std::queue<TValue> &value) -> void {
    std::queue<TValue> temp = value;
    while (!temp.empty()) {
        std::cout << temp.front() << std::endl;
        temp.pop();
    }
}

template<typename TValue>
constexpr auto t1(const TValue &nm) -> void {
    std::cout << nm << std::endl;
}

template<typename TValue>
constexpr auto t1(const std::shared_ptr<TValue> &nm) -> void {
    t1<TValue>(*nm);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::shared_ptr<const int> s_ptr = std::make_shared<const int>(7);
    t1(s_ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

This code fails to compile (https://godbolt.org/z/crvKb7rEz):

> error C2338: static_assert failed: 'The C++ Standard forbids containers of const elements because allocator is ill-formed.'

I've tried to change template with `shared_ptr` like:

```cpp
template<typename TValue>
constexpr auto t1(const std::shared_ptr<TValue> &nm) -> void {
    const int temp = *nm;
    t1<TValue>(temp);
}
```

It results in the same error.
I've also tried to get the 'TValue' type:

```cpp
template<typename TValue>
constexpr auto t1(const std::shared_ptr<TValue> &nm) -> void {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<TValue, const int>){
        static_assert(false, "??");
    }
    t1<TValue>(*nm);
}
```

`static_assert` is triggered.
That means 'TValue' is 'const std::string'.

Accidentally, I've removed `<TValue>` like this:

```cpp
template<typename TValue>
constexpr auto t1(const std::shared_ptr<TValue> &nm) -> void {
    t1(*nm);
}
```

Or:

```cpp
template<typename TValue>
constexpr auto t1(const std::shared_ptr<TValue> &nm) -> void {
    t1<std::remove_cv_t<TValue>>(*nm);
}
```

Also:

```cpp
template<typename TValue>
constexpr auto t1(const TValue &nm) -> void {
    std::cout << nm << std::endl;
}

template<typename TValue>
constexpr auto t1(const std::shared_ptr<TValue> &nm) -> void {
    t1<TValue>(*nm);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::shared_ptr<const int> s_ptr = std::make_shared<const int>(7);
    t1(s_ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

All of these work.

Why does the template wants to use `std::queue` overload when `<TValue>` euqal to `const int`? I except that it uses:

```cpp
template<typename TValue>
constexpr auto t1(const TValue &nm) -> void {
    std::cout << nm << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: *"why the template want to convert const std::string to std::queue"* It won't actually do the conversion, but it has to consider the `deque` overload, and that requires substituting `const std::string` into `std::deque<...>` if you explicitly specify the template parameter.

Comment: please include the error message as text in the question. Without the error message the question is incomprehensible. Please do not use images for text/code/error messages, include all necessary information directly in the question when possible

Comment: @Jarod42 could it be that the `-stdlib=libc++` version works solely because `std::deque` doesn't have a static assertion anywhere inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're explicitly providing the template argument `TValue` which results in an instantiation of `std::deque<const std::string>`.
`std::deque<T>` [requires a non-const, non-volatile `T`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque#Template_parameters), as the failed static assertion says:

> error: static assertion failed: `std::deque` must have a non-const, non-volatile `value_type`

- https://godbolt.org/z/PGY7nKW57

### Minimal Reproducible Example

To illustrate what's going on, here's a simplified version of your problem (https://godbolt.org/z/zYPhhb5dq):

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct container {
    static_assert(not std::is_const_v<T>);
};

template<typename T> void foo(container<T>);
template<typename T> void foo(T);

int main() {
    foo<const int>(0);
}
```

```
error: static assertion failed due to requirement '!std::is_const_v<const int>'
    5 |     static_assert(not std::is_const_v<T>);
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: in instantiation of template class 'container<const int>' requested here
   15 |     foo<const int>(0);
      |
```

### Solution

You can write `t1(*nm)` instead.
The difference here is that `std::deque<const std::string>` is never instantiated.
Instead, substitution into `t1(std::deque)` would fail because `*nm` is a `const std::string` and `TValue` in `std::deque<TValue>` cannot be deduced from `const std::string`.

```cpp
template<typename TValue>
constexpr auto t1(const std::shared_ptr<TValue> &nm) -> void {
    t1(*nm); // OK
}
```

`t1<std::remove_cv_t<TValue>>(*nm);` also works (though you shouldn't write it) because you instantiate `std::deque<std::string>` instead.
This is valid, however, overload resolution will pick `t1(const T&)` because there is no implicit conversion from `std::string` to `std::deque`.

**You should write `t1(*nm);`** It's generally better to deduce template parameters, not provide them explicitly.

---

#### Note on SFINAE-friendliness

The underlying issue is that `static_assert` isn't SFINAE-friendly, i.e. it results in errors that come *after* substitution.
In C++20, it is possible to use constraints instead of `static_assert` while having the same template parameters:

```cpp
template <typename T>
  requires (not std::is_const_v<T>) // analogous for std::deque
struct container { };
```

If this is done, `foo<const int>(0)` is valid (https://godbolt.org/z/TWKxs99Yj).

I don't believe it is legal for `std::deque` to have such constraints.
If it had them, your code would work.

Comment: Upvoted but I suggest adding another example where `container` is SFINAE-friendly with respect to the const check.

Comment: Emm, I know it wants to use the overload `std::queue` version, but why? In my third code block of the question, I make sure that `TValue` euqals `const std::string`. Shouldn't it use the `const std::string` overload?

Comment: @MikuSoft it doesn't want to use that overload. `std::queue` wouldn't win in overload resolution further down the line. The problem is that `std::queue` gets instantiated outside the immediate context of the function call, and you run into a failed `static_assert` before a decision is made which function should be called.